# How to replace strings using java String.replaceAll() excluding some patterns?

Tags: java, regex

I am using `String.Replaceall` to replace forward slash `/`  followed or preceded by a space with a comma followed by space `", "` EXCEPT some patterns (for example  `n/v`, `n/d` should not be affected)

ALL the following inputs

```
"nausea/vomiting"
"nausea /vomiting"
"nausea/ vomiting"
"nausea / vomiting"
```

Should be outputted as

```
 nausea, vomiting
```

HOWEVER ALL the following inputs

```
"user have n/v but not other/ complications"
"user have n/d but not other / complications"
```

Should be outputted as follows

```
"user have n/v but not other, complications"
"user have n/d but not other, complications"
```

I have tried

```
String source= "nausea/vomiting"
String regex= "([^n/v])(\\s*/\\s*)";
source.replaceAll(regex, ", ");
```

But it cuts the a before / and gives me nause , vomiting

Does any body know a solution?

Comment: This is really a regex question; you should tag it with the regex tag.

Comment: I posted it here in case there are some other means to do it in java.

Answer (score 0):

`[^n/v]` is a *character class*, and means *anything except a `n`, `/` or a `v`*.

You are probably looking for something like a *negative lookbehind*:

```
String regex= "(?<!\\bn)(\\s*/\\s*)";
```

This will match any of your slash and space combinations that are not preceded by just an `n`, and works for all your examples. You can read more on lookaround [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: How about if I don't want to match n/x? But I only want to match n/v and n/d? I want to check what n is followed by. It matters if it is followed by n or v or anything else that I don't care.

Answer (score 0):

Your first capturing group, `([^n/v])`, captures any single character that is not the letter `n`, the letter `v`, or a slash (`/`). In this case, it's matching the `a` at the end of `nausea` and capturing it to be replaced.

You need to be a bit more clear about what you are and are not replacing here. Do you just want to make sure there's a comma instead when it doesn't end in "vomiting" or "d"? You can use non-capturing groups to indicate this:

`(?=asdf)` does not capture but when placed at the end ensures that right after the match the string will contain `asdf`; `(?!asdf)` ensures that it will *not*. Whichever you use, the question mark after the initial parenthesis ensures that any text it matches will not be returned or replaced when the match is found.

Also, do not forget that in Java source you must always double up any backslashes you put in string literals.